How to Automatically Align 3D Molecular Models with Specific Image Orientations
I am currently using Gaussian16 quantum chemistry software to obtain some data, and then using Mathematica for visualization and data processing. Now I'm facing a visualization issue.
Through the log file obtained from the calculation, Mathematica can import it and use MoleculePlot3D to draw a 3D molecular diagram. The drawback is that I need to manually adjust the direction of the 3D diagram to match the image (the image is created by others and cannot be changed). Actually, the image has a pattern, which is that N-B-N these three are regular, as shown in the figure below.

SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];

path = "s0.log";
mol = Import[path, "GaussianLog"];

MoleculePlot3D[mol]

log and picture you can download in this
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/qupf9jiqjzk75j0oygxnn/AFOt_shJkd-janpg_jZnmTI?rlkey=181qzztkxb6eq0jkk59199ow0&st=in245ips&dl=0
